# Windows 7 not appearing on grub2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I just installed Ubuntu 14 on a separate hard drive from Windows 7.

But when grub2 boots up, I only see options to boot Ubuntu, Windows 7 is nowhere in sight.

I've had to manually boot the hard drive with windows 7 on it to get in.

Here's my disc info:

- `/dev/sda1` HPFS/NTFS (Windows 7 drive)
- `/dev/sdb1` HPFS/NTFS (TB drive)
- `/dev/sdc1` EFI System FAT (Ubuntu drive, grub is installed on this one)

If I run `sudo update-grub` I get:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Running `sudo parted -l` shows:

```
Model: ATA Crucial_CT240M50 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  240GB  240GB  primary  ntfs         boot


Model: ATA WDC WD10EZRX-00A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA WDC WD2500JS-00M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                 boot
 2      538MB   242GB  241GB   ext4
 3      242GB   250GB  8471MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Any ideas on how to get Windows 7 to appear?

Comment: OK, that's strange. Could you also add the output of `sudo parted -l` please? A possible (bad) workaround is to edit the `menu.cfg` file manually.

Comment: Ok, added the output.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo os-prober`

Comment: Huh, nothing at all actually.

Comment: You cannot. Windows is BIOS boot and Ubuntu on sdc is UEFI boot. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. Or once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. Or grub booted in UEFI mode only will boot other installs in UEFI mode. You can add a bios_grub (1MB unformatted with bios_grub flag) partition to sdc, and use Boot-Repair to convert UEFI to BIOS boot on gpt drive. See this:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_UEFI_or_Legacy_mode

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu and run this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

That will detect the available operating systems and generate the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file.

Have you really installed Ubuntu on a FAT32 drive? I'm very surpized that works and you can expect to have all sorts of issues with permissions down the line. If this is a new install I recommend you reinstall and chose a Linux filesystem like ext4.

Comment: Ran that command already

Generating grub configuration file ...

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic

Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration....


no windows to be found.
I think it is ex4, but there's like three partitions ubuntu created and one of them is fat32

Comment: @user283611 please [edit] your question and include the output of the command. Was the Windows drive plugged in when you ran it?

Comment: yes all the drives are mounted. I edited the question so you can see the output.